# How can I activate the Linux version of Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Enterprise?

Tags: sql-server, product-key, software-activation

I [followed the steps on the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-ver16&preserve-view=true#install) to install SQL Server 2022 on Ubuntu Server. After I entered the command on step 4 of the instructions to enter the setup wizard, I selected the Enterprise edition when prompted to select an edition, but it didn't prompt me to enter a product key. Where I am supposed to put in my SQL Server Enterprise product key to activate the software? Is it even necessary to enter the key? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn’t appear you’re supposed to literally enter a product key. You just need a license but sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup would have been the step that allowed you enter it

Comment: So, is it an honours system with no "activation" required?

Comment: That must be the case.

Comment: OK, I will answer my own question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No activation is required on the Linux version of SQL Server, but to use it "legally", you must own a licence to use the version of SQL Server that you selected during the initial setup.

Source: User:Ramhound in comments, Microsoft